# wso2:vault-lookup() retuns empty value in Wso2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am new to WSO2 and I am trying to use secure vault to encrypt the password which is used to connect to the host.I used ciphertool.bat (As my server is on Windows) to encrypt the password.

[ciphertool password encryption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55mGc.png)

An entry has also been made in API Manager carbon console in secure vault i.e /_system/config/repository/components/secure-vault

[Entry in API Manager Carbon Console Secure Vault location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO9EL.png)

But when reference is made to alias as expression="wso2:vault-lookup('pwd')" the value returned is empty (This is referenced in Log for testing)

Can anyone tell me if anything is wrong in the way its done or is any configuration missed?

Comment: Please check https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Encrypting+Secure+Endpoint+Passwords

Comment: I had gone through the posted article @Pubci but it didn't help my problem. What I wanted to know is if I am using wso2:vault-lookup('alias') in my mediation and have the alias defined in system/config/repository/components/secure-vault , it should give the decrypted value. But it's giving me nothing. So am I missing anything

Comment: What is your deployment? Is it distributed setup? Is your gateways connected to database? what is your apim version?

Comment: Api manager version is 2.6.0 and it's a set up in my local without connection to any database. The password I am looking for ,which needs decryption is the one which is used to connect to the host. Which is basic auth

Comment: @Pubci, wso2:vault-lookup('alias') does work when the API is marked as secured in the implementation tab while defining API. However, if we don't mark API as secure and just add entry to system/config/repository/components/secure-vault and try to retrieve it using wso2:vault-lookup('alias')  , it doesn't work. So should we add anything else anywhere?